# How to display status of employer

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two tables, one is employer and Second is manager. I will match from one table to fetch which employer is working under which manager, now I want to display employer login or logout status, which will be recorded in another table with the value of 0 being logged out and 1 as logged in. how to display this? Below is my query: Button_status is 0 or 1

```
SELECT Button_status, user_id,updated_time FROM table1 a join table2 b on a.user_id=b.login_name WHERE b.Manager_Name='$_SESSION[login_user]'
```

Also, I just want status of each employer for today's date.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows->Button_status;?>">
```

Comment: Are your tables having these field names?

Comment: What result/error do you get right now with the current query?

Comment: Does `user_id` ever actual equal `login_name`? Those sound like the wrong columns to be joining on. You also need `Button_status` and the date column in your `where` clause.

Comment: Show your database structure with all 3 tables

Comment: It seems like employers are really employees. Even so, are managers not also employed?

Comment: @itsols No error it is just not displaying anything.

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, it is equal I have given name like that in two different tables and both correspond to same values